# How to transform a js array to make it by day

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const arr = [
    {"datetime":"2018/8/5","value":85,"type":"A"},
    {"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":7,"type":"B"},
    {"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":73,"type":"A"}
];
```

I have an array as you can see in the snippet. My issue is I need to check something per day:

1. For each day when `A value > 60` or when `B value > 6` then do something.
2. Else when `A value <= 60` and when `B value <= 6` then do something else.

And I don't know how to do this check with the current array structure as each step in the loop is a different day. I want to compare all values for one day at the same time.

Is it possible to transform the array to look like this? Then I will be able to compare day per day...

```
const arr = [
    {"datetime":"2018/8/5","valueA":85,"valueB":undefined},
    {"datetime":"2018/8/10","valueB":7,"valueA":73}
];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a the date groups by reducing into an object. Then just set the appropriate value in that object. In the end your array will be in the `Object.keys()` of the grouped object.

[*As you might surmise from the comments, the order of the final array is not guaranteed because object keys and values are not guaranteed. If your original data is ordered by date, you should say so in the question because there will be more efficient ways to do this if the order is guaranteed*].

```js
const arr = [{"datetime":"2018/8/5","value":85,"type":"A"},{"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":7,"type":"B"},{"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":73,"type":"A"}];

let groups = arr.reduce((obj, {datetime, value, type}) => {
  if (!obj[datetime]) obj[datetime] = {datetime, valueA:undefined, valueB:undefined} 
  let currentKey = type == 'A' ? "valueA" : "valueB"
  obj[datetime][currentKey] = value
  return obj
},{})

let newArr = Object.values(groups)
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: This does not guarantee that the resulting array will be in the same order as the input. Calling `Object.values` on an object gives an arbitrary order.

Comment: @Paulpro the order can't be guaranteed when grouping. One date might be at the beginning of the array and another might be at the end. Where would that object go in the final array? This might be an issue if th OP said the original array was sorted by date, but that is not known here. You should reconsider this downvote.

Comment: It can be guaranteed if the input array is ordered. E.g. timeseries data, which is what this looks like.

Comment: I agree @Paulpro if the original array is ordered, the OP should say so. If that's the case, there would be other solutions, which then someone would downvote because the OP never said the array was ordered. It's simple enough to sort the end result.

Comment: @Shidersz I commented on all the answers because I am afraid that if the OP uses them he may think they work for his case and happily use them (since it will usually end up actually being ordered the same as the array when he tries it, even though it is not guaranteed), and hide a bug that could take him or someone else a lot of time and effort to debug later when it crops up.

Comment: I think an answer should at least make a note about the potential for the result to be unordered even if the input is ordered, because it is likely that it does matter to the OP and it is also likely that they won't notice because it coincidentally comes out in the order they expect when they run it; but it may come back to bite them later. If the dates with in ISO 8610 like `"2018-08-05"` sorting it would be as simple as `newArr.sort( ({datetime: a}, {datetime: b}) => (a < b) ? 1 : (a > b) ? -1 : 0 );`, but since they're not in ISO 8601 it becomes much more complicated.

Comment: @Paulpro, I added a disclaimer. Maybe the OP will clarify one way of the other.

Answer (score 1):

This will transform the array as OP asked for, and will respect the order.

```js
const arr = [{"datetime":"2018/8/5","value":85,"type":"A"},
{"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":7,"type":"B"},
{"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":73,"type":"A"}];

var daysArr = []

arr.map(function(day){

    var keyName = 'value'+day.type
    var found = false
    var dayObj = {}

    for (var i=0; i < daysArr.length; i++) {
        if (daysArr[i].datetime === day.datetime) {
            daysArr[i][keyName] = day.value;
            found = true
            break
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        dayObj = {"datetime":day.datetime,valueA:undefined,valueB:undefined}
        dayObj[keyName] = day.value
        daysArr.push(dayObj)
    }

})

console.log(daysArr);
```

Comment: This does not guarantee that the resulting array will be in the same order as the input. `for ... in` iterates object keys in an arbitrary order.

Comment: Edited it. Not the fastest code, not the most modern but it is what the OP asked for. Order is retained.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be using `reduce()`. Note that if a `key` is not defined will return `undefined` (this is exemplified on the second log to the console), so I consider redundant to define, for example `"value-B": undefined`, unless you want to assign to it another default value.

**Warning:** As discussed on the comments, you should note that the order of the final result, may not be preserved.

```js
const arr = [
  {"datetime":"2018/8/5","value":85,"type":"A"},
  {"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":7,"type":"B"},
  {"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":73,"type":"A"}
];

let res = arr.reduce((acc, {datetime, value, type: type}) =>
{
    acc[datetime] = acc[datetime] || {};
    Object.assign(acc[datetime], {datetime, [`value-${type}`]: value});
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(res));
console.log(Object.values(res)[0]["value-B"]);
```

Comment: This does not guarantee that the resulting array will be in the same order as the input. Calling `Object.values` on an object gives an arbitrary order.

Comment: @Paulpro And where the OP explicitly says he wants to keep the order?

Comment: I never said he does.

Comment: @Paulpro OP needs to compare the A and B values for each date, so I think it's pretty clear that the result order doesn't matter

Comment: @Slai He also said he wants to do "something" or "something else" for each one. I don't think it is clear at all that doing those things in order doesn't matter. In fact, I think the opposite is more likely true.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<script type="text/javascript">
const arr = [{"datetime":"2018/8/5","value":85,"type":"A"},
{"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":7,"type":"B"},
{"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":73,"type":"A"}];

var new_arr = group_items(arr)
console.log(new_arr)

function group_items(arr)
{
    var ret_arr = []
    for(var x=0;x<arr.length;x++)
    {
        var cur_date = arr[x].datetime
        var pos = lookup_date(cur_date, ret_arr)

        var obj = {}
        obj.datetime = cur_date
        if(pos != false)
        {
            //add to existing item

            if(arr[x].type == 'A')
            {
                ret_arr[pos].valueA = arr[x].value
            }
            else if(arr[x].type == 'B')
            {
                ret_arr[pos].valueB = arr[x].value
            }

        }
        else{
            if(arr[x].type == 'A')
            {
                obj.valueA = arr[x].value
            }
            else if(arr[x].type == 'B')
            {
                obj.valueB = arr[x].value
            }
            ret_arr.push(obj)
        }

    }

    return ret_arr
}

function lookup_date(date, arr)
{
    /*
        returns the position in arr of date
    */
    var retval = false
    for(var x=0;x<arr.length;x++)
    {
        if(arr[x].datetime == date)
        {
            retval = x
            break
        }
    }

    return retval
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the final array to include the datetimes in the same order as the original, then you can just make an object that maps datetimes to the corresponding values and then use `Object.values` to get the final array. This approach does not guarantee order, since objects are unordered data structures:

```js
const arr = [
  {"datetime":"2018/8/5","value":85,"type":"A"},
  {"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":7,"type":"B"},
  {"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":73,"type":"A"}
];

const values_by_date = { };
arr.forEach( ({ datetime, type, value }) =>
  values_by_date[ datetime ] = { 
    datetime/*, valueA: undefined, valueB: undefined*/,
    ...values_by_date[ datetime ], [`value${type}`]: value 
  }
);

const result = Object.values( values_by_date );
console.log( result );
```

If you need the final array to include the datetimes in the same order as the original array and the original array is already sorted by datetime, you can do it in a single pass like this:

```js
const arr = [
  {"datetime":"2018/8/5","value":85,"type":"A"},
  {"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":7,"type":"B"},
  {"datetime":"2018/8/10","value":73,"type":"A"}
];

const result = arr.reduce( ({ result, datetime: prev }, { datetime, type, value }) => {
  if ( datetime !== prev )
    result.push( { datetime/*, valueA: undefined, valueB: undefined*/ } );
  Object.assign( result[ result.length - 1 ], { [`value${type}`]: value } );
  return { result, datetime };
}, { result: [] } ).result;

console.log( result );
```

Note: In either snippet you can uncomment `/*, valueA: undefined, valueB: undefined*/` if you want the resulting objects to include properties for the missing values.